# How do I factory reset a 3com 5500G-EI?

Tags: switch, 3com

I have inherited a 3com 5500G-EI without any configuration docs,
and I need to reset it to factory defaults.
What is the best procedure to do this?

Answer (score 2):

When using the console port to access the boot menu, the option  is available for one second. It is possible to hold  after reboot before the message is output to gain access to the boot menu.
By default, console messages are only visible for one Switch in a stack of switches. Use the 
**info-center switch-on all** command to output all the console output from all units in a stack to one of the console sessions.

The following commands are used to return the switch to factory default settings:

**<5500G-EI>reset saved-configuration** – This command will remove the user 
saved configuration file. To see which file will be 
deleted, enter display startup .

**[5500G-EI]change self-unit to auto-numbering** – This command will remove any saved Switch unit number (enter display ftm topo to see which switches in a stack are configured with a manual unit number, these are marked with priority 5, automatic numbered switches are marked with a priority of 10).

**[5500G-SI]rsa local-key-pair destroy** – This command will remove any local rsa keys used for SSH access.

**<5500G-SI>startup bootrom-access enable** – This command will re-enable access to the bootrom.

From the boot menu, the following commands may be used to select the appropriate defaults:
**Modify bootrom password** – Factory default is no bootrom password.
**Skip current configuration file** – Factory default is process configuration file.
**Set bootrom password recovery** – Factory default is enable bootrom password 
recovery.
**Set switch startup mode** – Factory default is fast startup.

**<5500G-EI> undo clock timezone** – This command will return the timezone to the 
factory default UTC timezone.  Enter display clock to see what timezone is configured.